# Problem with importing external Java library in Groovy Evaluator of Streamsets DataCollector

Tags: java, groovy, streamsets

I am trying to configure the Groovy Evaluator properly in the Streamsets DataCollector software. I am using 3rd party Java library `geohash-java` (see https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java). I downloaded the library from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.hsr/geohash/1.4.0 and successfully imported it on the External Libraries page.

I use the following Groovy code to import the library:
`import ch.hsr.geohash.GeoHash`.

When running in the preview mode I get the following error:

```
SCRIPTING_04 - Script sent record to error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Geohash for class: Script13
```

With the details:

```
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.ScriptingProcessorInitDestroyBindings$Err.write(ScriptingProcessorInitDestroyBindings.java:60)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.ScriptingProcessorInitDestroyBindings$Err$write.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at Script13.run(Script13.groovy:106)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72)
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.AbstractScriptingProcessor.runScript(AbstractScriptingProcessor.java:344)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.AbstractScriptingProcessor.runScript(AbstractScriptingProcessor.java:204)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.AbstractScriptingProcessor.runBatch(AbstractScriptingProcessor.java:199)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.stage.processor.scripting.AbstractScriptingProcessor.process(AbstractScriptingProcessor.java:176)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.SingleLaneProcessor.process(SingleLaneProcessor.java:95)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.api.base.configurablestage.DProcessor.process(DProcessor.java:35)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.lambda$execute$2(StageRuntime.java:299)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:244)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.execute(StageRuntime.java:311)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StagePipe.process(StagePipe.java:221)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.lambda$runSourceLessBatch$0(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:364)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.PipeRunner.acceptConsumer(PipeRunner.java:207)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.PipeRunner.forEachInternal(PipeRunner.java:152)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.PipeRunner.executeBatch(PipeRunner.java:132)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.runSourceLessBatch(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:360)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.preview.PreviewPipelineRunner.processBatch(PreviewPipelineRunner.java:284)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime$3.run(StageRuntime.java:383)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageRuntime.processBatch(StageRuntime.java:379)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.runner.StageContext.processBatch(StageContext.java:299)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.dirspooler.SpoolDirRunnable.produce(SpoolDirRunnable.java:326)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.dirspooler.SpoolDirRunnable.run(SpoolDirRunnable.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:34)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeRunnable.run(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:188)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.lambda$call$0(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:226)
    at com.streamsets.datacollector.security.GroupsInScope.execute(GroupsInScope.java:34)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeCallable.call(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:222)
    at com.streamsets.pipeline.lib.executor.SafeScheduledExecutorService$SafeRunnable.run(SafeScheduledExecutorService.java:188)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could only use the library with an alias binding.

```
import ch.hsr.geohash.GeoHash as geohash
```